# Converting the subquery into JavaScript to use in Node

Tags: javascript, subquery, arangodb, aql

I have tried to retrieve the documents attached to the vertex. I broke down the tasks and with help from Stack Overflow, I was able to find a solution using sub queries. This works super fine.

Sub query:

```
LET startVertex = (
FOR doc IN spec
FILTER doc.serial_no == '"12345abc"'
LIMIT 1
RETURN doc._id
)[0]

FOR v IN 1 ANY startVertex belongs_to 
RETURN v
```

How can I use this in server.js file, so that I can make connection with ArangoDB when run the file.

Comment: What do you mean by server.js? A Node.js script that retrieves data from ArangoDB and prints it to console? Or an HTTP server with an endpoint that returns it upon client request on the certain route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the arangojs module:

https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs

For example:

```js
const arangojs = require('arangojs');

const db = new arangojs.Database({
  url: 'http://localhost:8529/or/whatever'
});
db.useDatabase('databaseName');
db.useBasicAuth('usename', 'password');

db.query(
  'insert query here', 
  {
    bindVar1: 'value',
    bindVar2: 'value',
  }
}).then(function(cursor) {
  cursor.all().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Comment: this works but now the query has been updated::you have to add (aql`´)

Comment: Do you really? I understood that aql`´ and using the bindVar object are equivalent, do you have to use both?

Comment: yes the code works super fine..and yes i used both !!